# How to bind functions to the JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, hasownproperty

```
function Person(_name, _id, _salary){
    this.Name = _name;
    this.Id = _id;
    this.Salary = _salary;
}

Person.prototype.f_IncreaseSalary = function( _percentage ){
    this.Salary *= _percentage;
}

var per = new Person("cem",10,15000);
```

1) **I can access to `per.f_IncreaseSalary(0.2)` but what if i create this object from JSON string how can i access f_IncreaseSalary function?**

```
var sPer = {"Person" : {"Name":"Cem", "Id":10, "Salary":15000} };
sPer.f_IncreaseSalary(0.2); // it won't!
```

2) **How can i create sPer object which has functions of Person class?**

3) **How can i understand `sPer` has `f_IncreaseSalary` function?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Person` prototype and the JSON object which has a property `Person` are completely unrelated. You'll need to explicitly create a new object with `new Person(...)` and the data from the JSON object:

```
var sPer = {"Person" : {"Name":"Cem", "Id":10, "Salary":15000} };
var per = new Person(sPer.Person.Name, sPer.Person.Id, sPer.Person.Salary);
per.f_IncreaseSalary(0.2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The object literal you are creating is **not** a Person object. It is an unnamed object with the property 'Person' that has properties that are the same as your person object.

```
var personData = sPer.Person;
var p = new Person( personData.Name, personData.Id, personData.Salary);
p.f_IncreaseSalary(0.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

JSON is an acronym of Javascript Object Notation, which basically, once you create an object from a JSON String, you have an object with properties.

So for your example,

```
var sPer = {"Person" : {"Name":"Cem", "Id":10, "Salary":15000} };
```

You are creating an object literal which is not identical to your `Person` object (that you declared). Your `sPer` basically allows you to do this...

//Changing values in Javascript;

```
sPer.Salary = 100000;
sPer.Name = "John";
sPer.Id = 200;
```

It won't have the function:

```
Person.prototype.f_IncreaseSalary = function( _percentage ){
    this.Salary *= _percentage;
}
```

As you cannot create functions in JSON.

Hope this helps.